# Socket multiplexing with select() does not work as expecting

Tags: c, sockets, select

I'm trying to create a server that listens to two different ports, reads a message from the respective socket and prints it to stdout. When I connect for the first time to any of the available ports, the program works as expected. Then, when I try to connect to the second port, connect() will simply not unblock.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr1;
    struct sockaddr_in addr2;
    int srv_fd1;
    int srv_fd2;
    int srv_fd;
    int accept_fd;
    fd_set srv_fds;
    char mem[1024];

    if ((srv_fd1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1 ||
        (srv_fd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    addr1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr1.sin_port   = htons(16000);
    addr1.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    addr2.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr2.sin_port   = htons(16001);
    addr2.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(srv_fd1, (struct sockaddr *)&addr1, (socklen_t)sizeof(addr1)) == -1 ||
        bind(srv_fd2, (struct sockaddr *)&addr2, (socklen_t)sizeof(addr2)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "bind(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(srv_fd1, 128) == -1 || listen(srv_fd2, 128) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "listen(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FD_ZERO(&srv_fds);
    FD_SET(srv_fd1, &srv_fds);
    FD_SET(srv_fd2, &srv_fds);

    while (select(srv_fd2 +1, &srv_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) != -1) {

        printf("Inside loop\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        memset(mem, 0, 1024);

        if (FD_ISSET(srv_fd1, &srv_fds))
            srv_fd = srv_fd1;
        else if (FD_ISSET(srv_fd2, &srv_fds))
            srv_fd = srv_fd2;

        accept_fd = accept(srv_fd, NULL, NULL);
        if (accept_fd == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "accept(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        read(accept_fd, mem, 1023);
        printf("%s", mem);

        close(accept_fd);
    }

    close(srv_fd1);
    close(srv_fd2);
    return 0;
}
```

Demonstration of the problem with telnet:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 16000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
FIRST ATTEMPT
Connection closed by foreign host.

$ telnet 127.0.0.1 16001
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
SECOND ATTEMPT
^]

telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

Server response:

```
$ ./test
Inside loop
FIRST ATTEMPT
^C
```

Comment: you need to reinitialize ``srv_fds`` in each iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do

```
FD_ZERO(&srv_fds);
FD_SET(srv_fd1, &srv_fds);
FD_SET(srv_fd2, &srv_fds);
```

each time before you call *select*, because that one resets `srv_fds` to indicate which *fd* has something. In your case the first call of `select` cancel `FD_SET(srv_fd2, &srv_fds);` so the second call of `select` only manages `srv_fd1`

Note doing `srv_fd2 +1` you also suppose `srv_fd2 > srv_fd1` which can be false.

You also suppose you have only one ready doing

```
   if (FD_ISSET(srv_fd1, &srv_fds))
        srv_fd = srv_fd1;
    else if (FD_ISSET(srv_fd2, &srv_fds))
        srv_fd = srv_fd2;
   ...
```

but you can have them both ready.

---

A way to do can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define NSOCK 2
#define FIRST_PORT 16000

/* returns the max descriptor */
int do_fd_set(int * srv_fd, fd_set * srv_fds)
{
  int r = 0;
  int i;

  FD_ZERO(srv_fds);

  for (i = 0; i != NSOCK; ++i) {
    FD_SET(srv_fd[i], srv_fds);
    if (srv_fd[i] > r)
      r = srv_fd[i];
  }

  return r;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int srv_fd[NSOCK];
    fd_set srv_fds;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i != NSOCK; ++i) {
      struct sockaddr_in addr;

      if ((srv_fd[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      addr.sin_port   = htons(FIRST_PORT + i);
      addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

      if (bind(srv_fd[i], (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t)sizeof(addr)) == -1)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "bind(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      if (listen(srv_fd[i], 128) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "listen(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

    while (select(do_fd_set(srv_fd, &srv_fds) + 1, &srv_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) != -1) {
      printf("Inside loop\n");

      for (int i = 0; i != NSOCK; ++i) {
        if (FD_ISSET(srv_fd[i], &srv_fds)) {
          char mem[1024];
          int accept_fd;

          memset(mem, 0, 1024);
          accept_fd = accept(srv_fd[i], NULL, NULL);
          if (accept_fd == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "accept(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
          read(accept_fd, mem, sizeof(mem) - 1);
          printf("from port %d : %s\n", FIRST_PORT + i, mem);
          close(accept_fd);
        }
      }
    }

    /* probably never reach that code */
    for (i = 0; i != NSOCK; ++i)
      close(srv_fd[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall so.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Inside loop
from port 16000 : aze

Inside loop
from port 16000 : qsd

Inside loop
from port 16001 : wxc

^C
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

doing in an other terminal :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ telnet localhost 16000
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
aze
Connection closed by foreign host.
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ telnet localhost 16000
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
qsd
Connection closed by foreign host.
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ telnet localhost 16001
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
wxc
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: I thought of mentioning srv_fd2 > srv_fd1 part, but in the simple OP shown example since it is guaranteed that socket always returns lowest unused descriptor, it follows that srv_fd2 > srv_fd1

Comment: @MohithReddy I wanted to warn the OP that this is not always true

Comment: So if both descriptors are ready, will not select() return immediately again on the next iteration? That is, I'm handling one at a time...

Comment: @Nick if they are ready at the same time you will manage only one of them but because resetting  the set for the next turn you will never manages the second one. You need to manage all the ready fd in the same turn. An hint : do not use separated variables for all but an array and use a function to do the FD_SET also return the max id or 0 when all is done

Comment: @Nick I edited my answer to add a proposal of code and executions

Answer (score 2):

bruno's answer diagnoses the problems correctly.  As a supplement, here is a working version of the relevant code:

```
while(1) {
    FD_ZERO(&srv_fds);
    FD_SET(srv_fd1, &srv_fds);
    FD_SET(srv_fd2, &srv_fds);

    int maxFD = (srv_fd1 > srv_fd2) ? srv_fd1 : srv_fd2;
    if (select(maxFD+1, &srv_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) break;

    [...]
```